# How can I get GtkWidget to expand?

Tags: gtk, glade

I am currently building a UI in Glade.

My widget tree looks like this:

[image]

My homescreen (`GtkFixed`) is horizontally and vertically expanded.
navigationbar (`GtkFixed`) is horizontally expanded and has a fixed height of 120.

I want the GtkToolbar to be horizontally and vertically expanded as well, but I can't get it to expand...

[image]

Full XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="width-request">1024</property>
    <property name="height-request">600</property>
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="width-request">1024</property>
        <property name="height-request">600</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkFixed" id="homescreen">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkFixed" id="navigationbar">
            <property name="height-request">120</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
            <property name="valign">end</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkToolbar">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can-focus">False</property>
                <property name="hexpand">True</property>
                <property name="vexpand">True</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkToolButton">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">__glade_unnamed_4</property>
                    <property name="use-underline">True</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="expand">False</property>
                    <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="x">0</property>
                <property name="y">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```